# Bertin 1953 map projection settings

Tags: coordinate-system

I am trying to use the Bertin 1953 map projection, as described in the book "Semiology of graphics" by Jacques Bertin. But I can't find the settings in any of my GIS software.
Does anybody have a solution ?

Comment: Do you mean the projection shown here: http://lmrhg.free.fr/fonds/Monde_Bertin_1937.pdf?

Comment: Is any further information given? Like how this map was created? Can you perhaps provide a scan.
If it is indeed the same projection that underdark points to, I doubt whether you will find an implementation in GIS software. It seems that the regional compensation means that larger errors are allowed in oceans, which may mean that there are many transformations needed to get the final map.

Comment: Hello,Thanks for your answers. @underdark: This is exactly the projection I'd like to use. The "Atelier de cartographie de Science-Po" allows to download some in their [Cartothèque](http://cartographie.sciences-po.fr/fr/cartotheque) But they are all PDF file. It is indeed a projection with regional compensation, meanning that each region has it own distortions. It seems that any GIS software allows to use it...I fear it means I'll have to make some drawing...Thanks for your help.

Comment: Except for Australia/NZ area, I can get something that looks similar using Lambert azimuthal equal area centered at 40,10.

Answer (score 4):

I also looked for a detailed description of this projection and couldn't find one. However, there is a very similar projection which Bertin also mentions in "Semiology of graphics" as one which is worth using. It is called [Briesemeister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammer_projection#Briesemeister) and is described in the book ["Flattening the Earth: Two Thousand Years of Map Projections"](http://bit.ly/Uaq6O1) by John P. Snyder (page 239). [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/4344444) is a demo I put together quickly with D3.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier if you could provide an EPSG code, if there is one, as we could have a look in the base of some projection library.

Comment: After some search, unfortunately, it seems that Bertin projections are not described by the EPSG.

Answer (score 2):

Bertin 1953 projection is now available in proj4 : 
https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4/blob/master/src/PJ_bertin1953.c
and through d3 https://github.com/d3/d3-geo-projection/blob/master/src/bertin.js

[image: Bertin 1953]

Credit to Philippe Rivière -- 
https://visionscarto.net/bertin-projection-1953

Comment: Since the github link seems broken. Here is the latest link to the Bertin projection on proj.org: https://proj.org/operations/projections/bertin1953.html